# Django URLconf loading

Tags: django, django-urls

I am reading Django's official docs, and there is this sentence on `reverse_lazy()`:

> It is useful for when you need to use a URL reversal before your project’s URLConf is loaded.

Could anybody explain what is meant by "URLConf loading"?

Answer (score 1):

URLconf is short for URL configuration.

Most of the time, your settings has

```
ROOT_URLCONF = 'myproject.urls'
```

in which case your URL conf is the `urls.py` in the inner project folder.

As the docs sugest, you can’t use `reverse` at module level in your settings or `urls.py`, because that code is loaded when the server starts before the `urls.py` have finished loading. In those cases, you can use `reverse_lazy`, which delays reversing the url until later.

Comment: I understand it. The question is: " what is Loading of URLConf? "

Comment: I’m not sure what you find confusing. If you understand that your URL conf is your `urls.py`, then "loading of your project’s URLConf" just means "loading of your project’s urls.py"

Comment: In the order that the code is executed to start the server, the modules are executed before the URLConf.  Therefore, the URLConf has not been "loaded" yet when the modules are "loaded," and you can't refer to it yet.